# Using sockets in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, asp.net-mvc-5, ip

I'm trying to include a network listening module in my application developed in C#. For that I created a socket like this

IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.185");

```
            /* Initializes the Listener */
            TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 5027);

            /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
            myList.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 5027...");
            Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                              myList.LocalEndpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

            Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);
```

But I have the following error in execution:
'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions'

can anyone please help me with this problem,

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you know that the port is definitely not being used by some thing else? The logging says 8001 and the listener says 5027.

Answer (score 0):

A socket error 10013 can be caused by the antivirus or firewall software. Basically, a needed socket connection is being denied. Socket error 10013 is a message which implies that a port is blocked and/or unreachable.

I would suggest you to disable antivirus software and Firewall together (as a test) on the computer temporarily and try connecting and check if it works.

Comment: i disable  my firewall and antivirus and still getting the same error

Comment: i am not getting error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" no more but this time im getting  error "the requested address is not valid in its context"  after i restart the TCP/IP stack.